# Correct way to load AngularJS templates for Webpack 4?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, webpack-4

So far I've been able to bundle up all our controllers/directives/services into 1 script and I also bundled all the vendor scripts into another script file.  Now I'm having trouble figuring out what the right way to load the AngularJS template files are.  We are currently using Grunt and just copying the exact folder structure over to the dist folder but clearly this won't work in Webpack.  Here is an example of our project structure(from the John Papa style guide)

[image]

My project inside the dist folder is currently rendered as follows:

[image]

Anybody have any input?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AngularJS templates are `html` files, so you need to add some loader for handling them.

1. You have multiple options, bundle those `html` files into the js bundle, using [html-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader), pros of this approach is that your app won't make ajax call for the template, cons, your js bundle size will become large.
   This will allow you to "require" your html template inside your controllers.
2. copy those raw files using [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin), this way it will work the same way it works with Grunt (providing `templateUrl` path to the file that was copied).
3. In-order to be specific regarding lazy-loaded files you can attach `.lazy.html` suffix.
   Then, enable [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader) on the `.lazy.html` files & assign it to `templateUrl`, and the regular once use with `template: require('template.html')`.

As of best practice, I would "require" critical templates so they will be in the js bundle, and lazy load (via `templateUrl`) non-critical ones.

This is an example of `webpack.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.lazy\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {},
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        exclude: /\.lazy\.html$/
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
            options: {
              minimize: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

```
// critical.component.js
angular.
  module('myApp').
  component('greetUser', {
    template: require('critical.html'),
    controller: function GreetUserController() {
      this.user = 'world';
    }
  });


// none-critical.component.js

angular.
  module('myApp').
  component('greetUser', {
    templateUrl: require('non-critical.lazy.html'),
    controller: function GreetUserController() {
      this.user = 'world';
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up requiring the templates in all the files as you suggested.  This seems to work for now although I'm not sure on the performance impact.

Comment: The only impact is the bundle size, I suggest you to mix both of the methods, cause if you have for example modals, there is good reason it to load while the app is loads, you can load it lazly using `templateUrl`

Comment: How do you exactly load it with templateUrl?  It doesn't seem to work for me.  With template, I do:
template: require('filename.html')

Comment: I've added an example of config, hope it helps

Comment: AngularJS is not HTML valid. For instance, `<div> {{ 45 < 60 ? 'hello' : 'world' }} </div>` is not valid HTML since there is an open but not closed `<` between the numbers...

Comment: <div><</div> as far as i know is valid html... since it looks for a closing tag, not just the chat <

Comment: Friends i am trying your solution but it is not working 
putting a require statement on template property and using html-loader is not displaying the template when i go to the link, but no error is reported in the console and i checked the bundled js file and the template exists in it, i do not now how to proceed further